# MarkLogic 7 boost relevance

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7

In MarkLogic, I can boost relevance score for certain documents.

For example if I have a document stored in `content` collection such as the below:

```
<Content xmlns="http://test.ww/common/content/v1.0">
  <DisplayName>Testing DisplayName</DisplayName>
</Content>
```

And I also have another document stored in `techno` collection such as the below

```
<Techno xmlns="http://test.ww/common/content/v1.0">
    <DisplayName>Testing DisplayName</DisplayName>
</Techno>
```

And I have another document in the `fun` collection with XML as below

```
<Fun xmlns="http://test.ww/common/content/v1.0">
    <DisplayName>Testing DisplayName</DisplayName>
</Fun>
```

If I do a search for the term `testing displayname`, I expect that documents in the content collection should have a higher relevance than documents in the `techno` collection. Ranking should be from Content->Techno->Fun. Basically if it is an exact match on the displayname I want MarkLogic to rank relevance with the `content` collection having the top relevance.

How  can I do this? I am using the search library.

Comment: With 'in the content collection' do you mean 'in document-collection `content`', or merely 'with root element `Content`'?

Comment: the document-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@navin rawat's answer is doing it on "write" and I wanted to point out that you can also do this on "read". which from your comment/question to him might be the way you want to go.

When you say "search library" do you mean the search:search library or cts:search?

If it's search:search you could do this with an additional query.

What you'll want to do is use `cts:collection-query()` and then boost its score by wrapping a `cts:word-query()` a the `cts:collection-query()` in an `cts:and-query()`. Then in the `cts:word-query()` use the weight parameter. the weight parameter allows you to "boots" scoring on parts of the query.

Ex:

```
let $queryText := "query here"
return 
  cts:search(
     fn:doc(),
     cts:or-query((
      cts:and-query((
       cts:word-query($queryText, (), 6.0),
       cts:collection-query("Content")
     )),
     cts:and-query((
      cts:word-query($queryText, (),4.0),
      cts:collection-query("Techno")
     )),
     cts:and-query((
      cts:word-query($queryText, (),2.0),
      cts:collection-query("Fun")
    )),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("DisplayName"), $queryText, "exact", 16.0)
 )


    ))
```

The `cts:word-query` with the `cts:collection-query` is allowing you to boot the "hit" based on the collection its in.

The `cts:element-value-query()` is boosting the score based on the element its in and the exact option telling marklogic to look for that exact text.

You'll have to play around with the numbers in the weight parameter

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve your requirement.

1. You should insert your document with $quality so that it can boost your relevance score.
2. You may use fields to boost the weight of sections of documents.

Comment: ok thank you. the first option is not applicable since there are quite a number of documents and changing the document quality will be tricky. The second option how do i go about using fields to boost the weight?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field contains this three elements and give different weight to them, then do a field-value-query on this field, you will return the result as the sequence you expect.